# Open Material UI DatePicker when clicking the input

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

I got this component which doesn't receive `onClick`.
I know I need to pass an `open` (`boolean`) prop but can't find a way to trigger it when clicking `MuiDatePicker`.

This is an image to clarify where I want to click
[image]

```
const DatePicker: FC<DatePickerProps> = ({ yearsPerRow = 3, ...props }) => {
return (
    <MuiDatePicker
        slotProps={{
            switchViewIcon: { sx: { display: 'none' } },
            openPickerIcon: {
                component: EventIcon,
                style: { fontSize: '16px' },
            },
        }}

        yearsPerRow={yearsPerRow}
        open={boolean} // this should be controlled by a click on the component
        {...props}
    />
);
};
```

Comment: Can you create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @JBrown it's here (the component i pasted should get the `open` prop). edited the prop in for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you could solve this but here is one solution. Create a click listener in a useEffect that checks to see if the focused input is in the dom. I use the MUI classnames plus a custom class to check for this. If it is in the dom, set the piece of state that tracks whether the picker is open to `true`. Note that I do not include the code for closing the popup as that is specific to your use case. You will need to set `isOpen` to false to close the modal though.

```
const MyPicker = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClick = () => {
      const isFocused = document.querySelector('.customPicker .Mui-focused');
      if (isFocused) { // If the dom contains the element, open the popup
        setIsOpen(true);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
      <DatePicker open={isOpen} className="customPicker"/> // Not including your other props
  );
};
```